# Can "process" be used as an intransitive verb?

Tags: grammar, verbs, intransitive-verbs

I am currently spending some time creating a (partial) [Liferay](http://www.liferay.com/) translation for the Greek language, and I came upon this original English message text:

> Your request processed successfully.

Can the verb "process" be used intransitively in this manner? Or would this be the correct form?

> Your request *was* processed successfully.

Comment: Wiktionary lists only the transitive meaning (except in an unrelated sense). Intransitive looks odd to me.

Comment: @Mechanicalsnail: at least a couple of online dictionaries that I have looked at seem to agree that there is no intransitive form of this verb. And, yes, the intransitive usage does seem odd...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Process* **is** an intransitive verb, but it means "walk in procession". Clergy and ministers process into a church service. It's pronounced differently, with the stress on the second syllable.

[ODO](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/process) doesn't allow *process* not to have an object, in the sense which is meant in your quote:

> *verb*
>   *[with object]*
>         perform a series of mechanical or chemical operations on (something) in order to change or preserve it:
>         *the salmon is quickly processed after harvest to preserve the flavour*
>           * deal with (someone or something) using an official procedure:
>               *the immigration authorities who processed him*
>           * *Computing* operate on (data) by means of a program.

However, it is also fairly common for computer output messages to omit the verb, headline-style; or to use jargon.

In the quoted message, it is clear what is meant: the request *went through the process*. But this use is jargon.

Comment: I think that a message along the lines of "request process complete" would be jargon. *That* message just seems like a mistake to me - and it is not the first one that I have encountered. I guess I will be correcting *more* than just the Greek language files...

Comment: No, "request process complete" means the process [noun] is complete. *Processed* as an intransitive verb means *went through the process*. It's not a mistake.

Comment: Agreed, _your request processed successfully_ is technical vocabulary (aka _jargon_). But it's stressed on the **first** syllable. That's the important part.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence

> Your sentence processed successfully.

is a grammatical sentence. It contains an example of a *derived intransitive* verb: a verb used intransitively, but whose meaning is derived from the meaning of a basic transitive sense of the same verb. In this case, the change in transitivity is used to indicate what is usually called the *middle voice*.

The middle voice construction uses a transitive verb as if it were intransitive, with the intransitive subject corresponding to the object of the original transitive verb. It has a meaning similar to the passive voice. The process is quite common in English, and extends to a good number of verbs, though somewhat restricted in meaning. Verbs which participate in the middle voice construction are typically those whose meaning is more specific as to what the object is.
Some examples:

> This cloth cuts easily.
>   This cloth folds easily.
>   Phenol and formaldehyde polymerize readily.
>   Bananas peel easily.
>   The program wouldn't run.
>   The script compiled successfully.

Other languages have a specific word-form for middle voice forms of a verb.

Answer (score 0):

You *can* just about get away with such usage - as evidenced by the fact that maybe 100 writers have felt it was okay to write [not process correctly](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22absolute%20implausibility%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbo=d&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22not%20process%20correctly%22&oq=%22not%20process%20correctly%22&gs_l=serp.3...7796.10108.2.11044.9.9.0.0.0.0.76.523.9.9.0...0.0...1c.1.d14aU8fxpLM&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.1355534169,d.d2k&fp=631c27e467ebe0f0&bpcl=40096503&biw=1328&bih=897) in contexts where it's almost always being used to mean *not **be processed** correctly*.

Some people will say it's "technical jargon", but given the increasing number of contexts where we need to speak of things being *processed [by admin/computer systems, etc.]*, I think it's a safe bet this usage will become increasingly common with each passing year. Even today, I wouldn't expect many people to seriously contend that it was "incorrect". I certainly don't.